# Why am I getting replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple error

Tags: python

I keep getting this error: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple
on this line of code:

```
print("'{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}'".format(question[3]), question[4], question[5], question[6])
```

here is my full code

```
def quiz(userID,topicID):
    with sqlite3.connect("Quiz.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
    score = 0
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE topicID=?",[(topicID)])
    questions = cursor.fetchall()
    numOfQuestions = 0 #use to help work out the score / %
    for question in questions:
        topic = question[1]
        print(question[2])
        print("'{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}'".format(question[3]), question[4], question[5], question[6])
        choice = input("Answer: ")
        if choice == question[7]:
            print("Correct")
            score += 1
            time.sleep(1)
            print("")
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
            numOfQuestions += 1
    #works our % to keep all quiz scores consistent
    score = int((score/numOfQuestions)*100)
    print("Your score was: ",score)
    insertData("INSERT INTO scores(userID,score,topicID) VALUES(?,?,?);")
    cursor.execute(insertData, [(userID), (score), (topic)])
    db.commit()
```

Comment: You passed 1 positional argument to `format` so the only valid replacement index is `{0}`. Had you fixed the parentheses it would still give a similar error because for 4 positional arguments the highest valid replacement index is `{3}`, not `{4}`.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you have a misplaced parenthesis.

It should more be

`print("'{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}'".format(question[3], question[4], question[5], question[6]))`

Answer (score 0):

Using indices greater than the total elements inside `{}` will cause `index out of range` while formatting.

Since you have used four elements inside `format()`, so the index range should be from 0 to 3, In your code `4` is causing `index out of range` error.

Try this:

```
print("'{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}'".format(question[3], question[4], question[5], question[6]))
```

or f-strings ([Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) for f-strings):

```
print(f"'{question[3]}', '{question[4]}', '{question[5]}', '{question[6]}'")
```