# (Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple) what's wrong?

Tags: python

What's wrong with my code?

```
marks = {"sungin": 80, "joonghyuk": 100,"sangsun": 70}

for mark in marks:
    if marks[mark] >90:
        print("{} {} pass".format(mark), marks[mark])
    
    else:
        print("{} {} fail".format(mark), marks[mark])
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print("{} {} fail".format(mark), marks[mark])
IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple
```

Comment: Your parentheses are wrong. It should be, e.g., `print("{} {} pass" .format(mark, marks[mark]))`

Comment: Should use `items()`, will simplify your code `for name, mark in marks.items(): print("{} {}".format(name, mark))`

Comment: Duplicate: [Why am I getting replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67983247/6045800)

Answer (score 1):

There is syntactical error in your code with the closing paranthesis. Please rectify your code per below.

```py
marks = {"sungin":80, "joonghyuk":100,"sangsun":70}

for mark in marks:
    if marks[mark] >90:
        print("{} {} pass" .format(mark, marks[mark]))
    else:
        print("{} {} fail" .format(mark, marks[mark]))
```